# Exception when running JasperReports on JasperServer

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

My Report works fine in iReport designer.
But when I try to run it on JasperServer it is giving me the following exception:

```
java.lang.Exception: 1 - oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

I have ojdbc6.jar in the classpath.

Comment: Is there more in the exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved the issue myself.

The problem was I haven't restarted the jasper server.
I had put the jar in the following path:
C:/Program Files/jasperreports-server-cp-4.5.0/apache-tomcat/lib

After having the jar in the classpath, I restarted the jasper server. Even then, it was not working and I restarted the PC and now it's working.

Thanks simont and mdhahlman for responding.

Comment: Glad you solved your issue. As described in the comments, in Stackoverflow, we don't rename a question "Solved" but we accept the best answer by clicking on the tick on the left of the answer - see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234 for more information. Btw, this is considered as rude not to accept any answer (see simont's coment about this)

Comment: Thanks for the info. I have been searching for the option to mark an answer as correct since long. I never thought it's this easy just to click on the 'tick' mark. Thank you so much. Love you Stackoverflow!

Answer (score 0):

Open iReport, go to `Tools > Otions > Ireport > CLASSPATH`, Then Add your oracle ODBC jar file there.